# Proof that a the sum of random variables is a sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I was self-studying some material on the sufficiency principle (below) but I'm not sure if I'm understanding the example right.

> Let X be a random sample from a Poisson distribution $(\mu)$. Use the definition of the sufficiency principle to show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $\mu$.

This is what I was able to work on myself:
$$
f_X(x ; \mu) = \frac{\mu^{\sum x_i}e^{-n\mu}}{\prod x_i!}
$$
Let $T = T(X) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $T$ ~ Poisson$(n\mu)$
$$
f_T(t ; \mu) = \frac{(n\mu)^{t}e^{-n\mu}}{t!}
$$
The following part is where I have doubts in my understanding,
$$
f_{X,T}(x ; t) = \mathbb{P}(X=x, T(x)=t) =  \mathbb{P}(X=x) \cdot I(T(X)= t)
$$
Which I'm guessing $I$ is an indicator variable (no mention about this in the material). From my understanding the indicator variable is only to ensure that $\mathbb{P}(X=x|T(x)= t) >0$ when $T(x)= t$ and that $\mathbb{P}(X=x|T(x)= t) =0$ when $T(x)\neq t$. If what I understand is true, doesn't this require $X$ and $T$ to be independent which I don't think they are.

I think I'm getting quite a lot of misconceptions so I'd appreciate any answers and clarifications.

Edit 1: Correcting the probability density symbols into probability symbols.

Comment: The indicator is there precisely because $P(X=x\mid T(X)=t)=\frac{P(X=x)}{P(T(X)=t)}$ if $T(X)=t$ and $P(X=x\mid T(X)=t)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @StubbornAtom So basically I understood it right, I thought $T$ and $X$ needed to be independent for that to be work.

Comment: $\mathbf X= \mathbf x$ has probability $0$ when  $\sum X_i \not = \sum x_i$